# C# - how to output part of a string to the console using indexes

Tags: c#, string

I'm writing a simple algorithm which ahould write in the console everytime a certain condition is met. Here is my code:

```
public static void StringTest()
{
    string stringToUse = "Ala BalaB JiBBerish Ala Jibberish Ala BalaB";

    int strLength = stringToUse.Length;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < strLength-4)
    {
        if (stringToUse[i] == stringToUse[(i + 4)] && stringToUse[(i + 1)] == stringToUse[(i + 3)])
            System.Console.WriteLine(stringToUse[i] + stringToUse[(i + 1)] + stringToUse[(i + 2)] + stringToUse[(i + 3)] + stringToUse[(i + 4)]);

        i++;
    }
}
```

But instead a literal string the output is numbers `434` . How should I format the ouput to get the actual letters if maybe someone could expain me why I don't get an error and those numbers instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding characters together - which will give you an integer value. It looks like you should probably just be using Substring:

```
Console.WriteLine(stringToUse.Substring(i, 5));
```

Alternatively you *could* format the characters:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
                  stringToUse[i],
                  stringToUse[i + 1],
                  stringToUse[i + 2],
                  stringToUse[i + 3],
                  stringToUse[i + 4]);
```

(Note the removal of extraneous parentheses, by the way. *Sometimes* extra brackets are useful - here they're just distracting.)

Comment: Thanks I just thought that maybe the indexes make some problem so I put the extra brackets

Comment: There is good overload of `WriteLine(char[] buff)`. Is it better to concatenate chars than use overloaded method???

Comment: @user854301: Actually, scratch that - we don't have a `char[]`, so it wouldn't help much. You'd have to call `ToCharArray`, which is a bit of a pain...

Comment: `System.Console.WriteLine(new[] {stringToUse[i], stringToUse[(i + 1)],stringToUse[(i + 2)],stringToUse[(i + 3)],stringToUse[(i + 4)]})` it works or I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user854301: Urgh, yes, you could do that. I thought you were going to take a chunk of the full char array. But Substring is nicer than any of this :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: agree with you, but yours amazing answers shouldn't contain such things), cause many of us take yours words as fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(stringToUse.substring(i, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string` ctor, as accessing by `[]` you get a `char` and *not* a `string`,

```
if (stringToUse[i] == stringToUse[(i + 4)] && stringToUse[(i + 1)] == stringToUse[(i + 3)])
{
     //Construct string from the sequence of chars you want...
     string result = new string(new char[]{stringToUse[i],
                                     stringToUse[(i + 1)], 
                                         stringToUse[(i + 2)],
                                            stringToUse[(i + 3)], 
                                               stringToUse[(i + 4)]});
     System.Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly make this an array - the `String(char[])` doesn't use a params array.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to match this:

```
public static void StringTest()
{
    string stringToUse = "Ala BalaB JiBBerish Ala Jibberish Ala BalaB";

    for (int i = 0; i < stringToUse.Length - 4; ++i)
    {
        if (stringToUse[i] == stringToUse[(i + 4)] &&
            stringToUse[(i + 1)] == stringToUse[(i + 3)])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(string.Empty,
                stringToUse[i],
                stringToUse[i + 1],
                stringToUse[i + 2],
                stringToUse[i + 3],
                stringToUse[i + 4]));
        }
    }
}
```

You should use a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop with an incrementing variable.

Comment: Thanks, why you think it's better with `for` loop?

Comment: Use a `for` loop when you have an incrementing/decrementing variable in your loop.  If you don't, use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`stringToUse[i]` is of type `char`. You're adding `char` values, hence the number. You want to use `stringToUse.Substring(i, 5)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Console.WriteLine(new[] {stringToUse[i], stringToUse[(i + 1)],stringToUse[(i + 2)],stringToUse[(i + 3)],stringToUse[(i + 4)]});
```

Comment: Nice use of `new[]` that is helpful too. Thanks